# Chart.js, returning an "date" array to plot the line graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, chart.js

in the database I have 3 data which i send via Rest-API to the Frontend Angular.
This works fine.

Here in browser console, you can see all three dataset, which I get through node.js via Rest-API:
[How it looks in the browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rM2C.png)

the result in the browser console looks like this:

```
0:
device_id: 2885679
list: Array(1)
0:
dt: 1596608643
main:
humidity: 10
pressure: 7.86
temp: 120.052
temp_max: 40.052
temp_min: 20.052
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
message: "1"
__v: 0
_id: "5f2a63857ce17d64d49465a4"
```

In the typescript component xy.component.ts my code looks like this:

```
export class ContactsComponent {

  chart: any = [];

  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactService.getContacts()
      .subscribe((res: any[]) => {

        console.log(res);

        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
          let temp_max = res[i]['list'].map(res => res.main.temp_max);
          let temp_min = res[i]['list'].map(res => res.main.temp_min);
          let alldates = res[i]['list'].map(res => res.dt)

          console.log(alldates)

          let deviceData = []
          alldates.forEach((res) => {
            let jsdate = new Date(res * 1000)
            deviceData.push(jsdate.toLocaleTimeString('en', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' }))
          })

          console.log(deviceData)
          

          this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
              labels: deviceData,
              datasets: [{
                data: temp_max,
                borderColor: '#3cba9f',
                fill: false
              }, {
                data: temp_min,
                borderColor: '#ffcc00',
                fill: false
              },
              ]
            },
            options: {
              legend: {
                display: false
              },
              scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                  display: true
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                  display: true
                }]
              }
            }
          })
        }
        })
      
  }
```

Why *`console.log(deviceData)`* only return the last value of the iteration?
I want to return all the values in `console.log(devicedata)` to draw a graph based on 3 timestamps. Here when I only get back 1 timestamp. Somehow it overwrites the values with the deviceData.push - Methode.
My goal is to draw all the datapoints i have (refer to the screenshots of the browser console).

Here how the graph is plot in the browser. It only plots one point, that is exactly the point of the console.log(deviceData):
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFwGb.png)

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Thanks
Eden

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(alldates)`?

Comment: I receive the timestamp [1596608643],but only from the first element of the array

Comment: It would be easier if instead of a screenshot you posted the result as text here. In the screenshot the `list` is collapsed so I cannot know how the data looks like

Comment: @JannesCarpentier, thanks for let me know. i updated the pic and also edited the post. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems every object in `res` has a list with only a single item. 
(`res[i]['list']` is an array of length 1)

Try logging this: 
(this takes all the values of each item and puts them in a single list)

```
let allvalues = [];
for (const item of res) {
  for (const measurement of item.list) {
    allvalues.push(measurement)
  }
}

console.log(allvalues);
```